# java.sql.ResultSet.getString() returns string with extra characters

Tags: java, xml, oracle, encoding, clob

I recently encountered a problem with trying to retrieve a **CLOB** value from **Oracle DB** with **Java**. There is a table that stores XML files as **CLOB**. `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is set to `AL32UTF8`. 
If I try to retrieve a value with `java.sql` package and using `ResultSet.getClob().getAsciiStream()` which then converts to the String with `UTF-8` encoding, then I get a valid XML.

But if I use **`ResultSet.getString()`**, XML parser fails with parsing exception.

While debugging, the extracted value looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3rpf.jpg). And it contains only half of the file.

Others XML files can be selected with **`ResultSet.getString()`** with no problem.
I didn't see any noticeable difference in ASCII representation of corrupted and valid XML.
Problem is fixed when you re-insert the same value to the database.

Can you please explain this behaviour of **`ResultSet.getString()`** method?

**Information about Oracle**

```
Oracle version is 12.1.0.2.0.
```

**Information about JDK:**

```
java version "1.7.0_131"  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.9.0.0.1.el7_3-x86_64 u131-b00)  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.131-b00, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like that particular clob is not actually encoded in UTF-8 as it claims, but UTF-16. It can occasionally happen that [data can be written to a column using a charset other than the NLS_CHARACTERSET](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG467). This explains why the problem is fixed when the data is re-inserted using the correct local charset.

I'm guessing that the Clob.getAsciiStream() has extra logic to deal with this sort of thing - maybe for incorrectly encoded [overlong (00-padded) UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Overlong_encodings), which is indistinguishable from UTF-16 for ASCII code points.

Answer (score -1):

I believe its returning CLOB's stored address for some reason and when you get it with getCLOB it makes it XML.

Check your stored XML you may forget a tag closing or may have some other syntax problem in your stored XML file.

Comment: Both `ResultSet.getString()` and `ResultSet.getClob()` return data from stored file, I checked. The stored XML is valid. And as I pointed out, the error goes away if I insert the same value in database